# Programmed Button in swift is not working

Tags: swift, uibutton

http://pastebin.com/MgQ7wx3g

So I am currently trying to get this button to work called Play button

```
let playButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    let image = UIImage(named: "VideoIcon.png") as UIImage?
    button.backgroundImage(for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressBackButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)

    return button
}()

func pressBackButton(button: UIButton) {
print("test")
    if let playVideoButtonURL = post?.videourl {

        let player = AVPlayer(url: playVideoButtonURL as URL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player:player)
        playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()

    }

}
```

When I click on it nothing happens even if the video code is wrong it should still print test. It's not giving me any errors on startup to work with either. The paste bin has my full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code given in question, with explicitly set frame.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set Frame
    self.playButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 2), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
    self.view.addSubview(playButton)
}
```

And its working perfectly and the "Test" is printing.

Then I checked your code you posted in given link. There I found this method `addConstraintsWithFormat` to set autolayout with visual format language. I replaced my code using this method.

```
self.view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-280-[v0(44)]", view: playButton)
self.view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-90-[v0(44)]", view: playButton)
```

It is also working.

From your code I can find that it's a `CollectionViewCell`. Could please try to add subviews to its `contentView`?

Comment: So i tried changing addSubview to contentView.addsubview the button still shows but still nothing happens when i click on it

Comment: @Tim I think its some constraint issue. First I set only horizontal constraint and forgot vertical constraint and it was not working.

Comment: Ah okay. I'll look into it then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The correct method signature is

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressBackButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and

```
func pressBackButton(_ button: UIButton) {
```